# How to get OS Process sampler in jmeter on linux environment

Tags: linux, performance, jmeter

I have installed Jmeter on ubuntu 14.0.4 but I am not able to see OS Process sampler in samplers list. Could you please let me know how to get OS process sampler for jmeter in ubuntu ?

I need to run shell script. I am doing this using ssh command sampler but in this we need to provide username,password and hostname to execute shell script but I do not want to pass this information.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed JMeter using package manager, the distribution may contain lesser number of plugins, maybe your Linux distribution maintainers have decided not to include the [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) into it.

The solutions are in:

1. Manually [download the latest version of JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and unpack it somewhere. Make sure you run it as `./jmeter` from its "bin" folder and not as `jmeter` in order to be sure that you are running the new version
2. You install the missing plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager OS Process Support]